# Computing the median of a nc file with nco

Tags: netcdf, median, nco, cdo-climate

As the title indicates, I want to compute the median of a `.nc` file named `sfcWind_1999.nc`. On each grid point (lat/lon combination) I want to compute the median in the `time` dimension. Is there any nco attribute that does this?

Comment: Does the solution have to be with NCO?  CDO has a percentile function that can calculate the median.

Answer (score 3):

The median is the 50th percentile, so you can use the percentile function in CDO to do this:

```
cdo timpctl,50 in.nc -timmin in.nc -timmax in.nc median.nc
```

The function needs to know the data bounding values to calculate the histogram, hence the piped min and max commands.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [manual](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#median), NCO can report the median of a single variable, but not, in one step, all variables in the file. So you would have to create the loop over variables yourself, either in Bash or in ncap2 directly.

```
ncap2 -O -v -s "foo=gsl_stats_median_from_sorted_data(var_nm.sort());print(foo)" in.nc out.nc
```

or

```
ncmdn var_nm in.nc
```